# Adding html element to data-bind in knockout with $data

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have this structure Here for a navigation purpose . However to add an arrow to end I have to add a icon tag `<i>` inside anchor .

```
<ul class="nav nav-list bs-docs-sidenav affix" data-bind="foreach:Folders">
                <li data-bind="css:{active: $data == chosenFolderId() }">
                <a href="#" data-bind="text: $data , click:goToFolder"></a></li>                   
            </ul>
```

Now what I want is to generate a anchor tag with something like this

```
<a href="#">Inbox<i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Button groups</a>
```

where `Inbox` comes from the knockout observable . Now how to achieve this ? Mind it I cannot add a span tag here cause the click event should be fired from anchor tag only . So the structure has to be what I mentioned above !

Any Ideas how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use knockout comment tags:

```
<!-- ko text: $data --><!-- /ko -->
```